# How to sort elements of a vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to input some values and then put those values in a vector. Then sorting them in ascending order and then getting min and max value.
The program is crashing every time I run it.

```
int main()
{
    int min_value = 0;
    int max_value = 0;
    int input_value;

    vector<int> value;

    cout << "Put four natural numbers as input: ";

    while (cin >> input_value) {
        if (input_value < min_value) {
            min_value = input_value;
            value.push_back(min_value);
        }

        else if (input_value > max_value) {
            max_value = input_value;
            value.push_back(max_value);
        }
    }

    std::sort(value.begin(), value.end());

    cout << "The smallest value you entered is " << value[0] << endl;
    cout << "The largest value you entered is " << value[value.size() - 1] << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Good answers are aprreciated

Comment: Why don't you just make your loop `for (int i; i<4; i++) {cin>>input_value; value.push_back(input_value);} `?

Comment: You'd see where your fault lies, if you ran it with a debugger.

Comment: Check your if conditions and starting values for your min and max...

Comment: Where's the limiting factor of your *four* values ? I.e. that entire while-loop and all the logic within looks wrong. Second, if the bogus logic in your while-block results in an empty vector (it easily can) both expressions in your `cout` statements at the end will invoke undefined behavior trying to reference elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

int main()

{

```
int min_value;

int max_value = 0;

int input_value = 0;



vector<int> value;



cout << "Put four natural numbers as input: ";



while (cin >> input_value) {

    if (input_value < min_value) {

        min_value = input_value;

        value.push_back(min_value);

    }

    else if (input_value > max_value) {

        max_value = input_value;

        value.push_back(max_value);

    }

}



std::sort(value.begin(), value.end());



cout << "The smallest value you entered is " << value[0] << endl;

cout << "The largest value you entered is " << value[value.size() - 1] << endl;



system("pause");



return 0;
```

}
The above code is working

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
  // Initialize the minimum with a large enough value.
  int min_value = 10000;
  // Initialize the maximum with a small enough value.
  int max_value = -10000;

  std::vector<int> value;
  {
    int input_value;
    while (std::cin >> input_value) {
      // Both "if" are necessary.
      if (input_value < min_value) {
        min_value = input_value;
      }
      if (input_value > max_value) {
        max_value = input_value;
      }
      value.push_back(input_value);
    }
  }

  if (value.empty()) {
    // Do something & early return.
    std::cout << "Empty input" << std::endl;
  } else {
    // Curious about why use std::sort here since you have already had max &
    // min. But if you want ...
    std::sort(value.begin(), value.end());
    std::cout << "The smallest value you entered is " << value.front()
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The largest value you entered is " << value.back();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The reason why your code in your answer seems to work because the uninitialized local variable min_value will be given an "random" value and was given an large positive value in this case. So this makes your solution "works".

But there are still some problems.

1. Uninitialized variables are dangerous and it makes your solution not going to work all time. Initialize explicitly your min_value & max_value.
2. The "else" is wrong. Please think about the case with only one element in the input. You can't catch the max_value in this case.
3. Check if the vector is empty before accessing it. Accessing empty vectors will throw exceptions.
4. Also think about negative input.